# Custom routed event sample

Tags: wpf

I need a complete example how to declare..and after use it a custom routed event.
    Actually i know the syntax but i don't know how to make it to work and how to use it 
    later. Can you give me simple complete example please (vb code is better for me).
    For example when clicking on a button to display text on a label.

Comment: `Button.Click` is already a `RoutedEvent`. If you want to assign a text value to a `Label` element, just respond to the `Click` event of the button... ?

Comment: Actually I don't want to assign a text value to a Label. Just I need a complete example how to declare and after use it a custom routed event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way I have used custom `RoutedEvent`: To trigger an animation whenever the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` changes (TextChanged Event):

In this instance I have created a class that derives from `TextBlock`. For the purposes of this demonstration we will call it `MyCustomTextBlock`.

First we define the `RoutedEvent`:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly TextChangedEvent As RoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TextChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, GetType(RoutedEventHandler), GetType(MyCustomTextBlock))
```

And we define the RoutedEeventHandler:

```
Public Custom Event TextChanged As RoutedEventHandler

    AddHandler(ByVal value As RoutedEventHandler)
        Me.AddHandler(TextChangedEvent, value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As RoutedEventHandler)
        Me.RemoveHandler(TextChangedEvent, value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
         Me.RaiseEvent(e)
    End RaiseEvent

End Event
```

Next, SHADOW the `Text` property declaration so that you can specify a Callback method:

```
Public Shared Shadows TextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", GetType(String), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TextPropertyChanged)))
```

EDIT: In the above `DependencyProperty` registration, I use `Reflection` to get the calling type because I use code snippets to inject `DependencyProperty` registration calls and it makes my snippets more dynamic. You can replace the above call with the following if you prefer not to import the `Reflection Namespace`:

```
Public Shared Shadows TextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", GetType(String), GetType(MyCustomTextBlock), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TextPropertyChanged)))
```

Define the callback method that will execute whenever the `Text` value changes, raising the `RoutedEvent`:

```
Private Shared Sub TextPropertyChanged(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    DirectCast(Sender, MyCustomTextBlock).RaiseEvent(New RoutedEventArgs(MyCustomTextBlock.TextChangedEvent))
End Sub
```

That is all for the code, now let's use it in XAML:

```
<local:MyCustomTextBlock>
    <local:MyCustomTextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyCustomTextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyCustomTextBlock.TextChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" AutoReverse="True"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:MyCustomTextBlock.Style>
</local:MyCustomTextBlock>
```

In the above trigger, I am simply scaling up the size of the `TextBlock` and then back down, all within 200 milliseconds which gives the user a subtle gesture that the text has changed, bringing their attention to the new value.

Also, if you haven't already, reference your assembly at the top of your xaml page:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyRoutedEventProject"/>
```

For simplicities sake, let VisualStudio hook it up for you. If you type `xmlns:local=` then Intellisense should pop up a list of namespaces to select from. Find the base namespace of your project and insert it:

[image]

This is a simple use of the `RoutedEvent`, but a real life use case that I use often. I hope it helps.